# New line break every array words in javascript string or php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have one string

```
string = "example string is cool and you're great for helping out A string is a sequence of characters"
```

I want to insert a line break every  words in array so it returns this:

```
const cars = [" is cool", "great for", "out"];
```

```
string = 'example string \n 
is cool\n 
and you're\n 
great for\n
helping\n
out\n
A string is a sequence of characters'
```

I am working with variables and cannot manually do this. I need a function that can take this string and handle it for me. and Between two array words is a newline

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following function:

```
function insertLineBreaks(string) {
  const words = string.split(' '); // Split the string into an array of words
  const breaks = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < words.length - 1; i++) {
    breaks.push(words[i] + ' ' + words[i + 1]); // Combine each pair of consecutive words with a space
  }

  return breaks.join('\n'); // Join the array with line breaks
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`str_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```php
$subject = "example string is cool and you're great for helping out A string is a sequence of characters";
$search = [" is cool", "great for", "out"];

$replace = array_map(fn ($s) => "$s\n", $search);

print_r(str_replace($search, $replace, $subject));
```